# How to save elements of sub-collection with repeated ids?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

The problem represented in the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/W7Rq9/

I have a collection of models (Photos). Each model (Photo) has its own collection (Tags) and sometimes the data stored in `tags` is repeated. And when I fetch my collection of `photos`, the repeated `tags` is deleted.

I think it will be more clearer in the example http://jsfiddle.net/W7Rq9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone will not allow two objects with the same id to be in the same collection.

You can give them all a unique id and/or change the attribute used as the object's id, but whatever attribute you set as the object id must be unique for all of the objects within a given collection.